# To Autosave HTML form data - Is using HTML5 localstorage a better option?

Tags: html, autosave

I have a form which has many fields to get input from the user. I need to implement Autosave functionality for this form, In the beginning I thought I will do it using PHP, AJAX. But after a small research I found out that we can use HTML5 localstorage object for the same purpose in which we dont have to use the server at all.

I believe HTML5 option will be a better option in terms of performance, but will that be better enough in security aspect as well.

Or is there any other option I need to consider, before starting the real work.

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, localstorage is a much better option for autosave than PHP & AJAX.

With the latter, you have to make AJAX requests (both to save the data, as well as to check if there is autosaved data when the page loads), as well as use up disk space to store the autosaved data.

With localstorage, the data is in the client's browser, which means there's no load on your server at all.

From a security aspect, in either case you want to make sure you don't autosave things like credit card or SSN numbers.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I already completed this functionality using localStorage(An amazing feature provided by HTML5) with 0 line server side script.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should mark this as the answer (or post your own answer and mark that as the answer) so that the question is closed.

Comment: @user2617611 To the left of answers, there are up and down arrows with the sum of the upvotes and downvotes in the middle. If you find an answer helpful, upvote it. If you find an answer that is really, really bad, then downvote it. If someone answers your question, click the green check mark beneath the arrows (accepting and answer gives the answerer 10 pts and you 2pts).